# Displaying photos from NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, nsdocumentdirectory

I'm developing this application on an iPad.

These codes for a 'Browse' button allows the user to view the photos from the iPad's gallery.

```
- (IBAction) BrowsePhoto:(id)sender
{
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
[popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,320)];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(200,200,-100,-100) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
self.popoverController = popover;
[imagePickerController  release];
}
```

When a photo is selected, it will be stored into the application using NSDocumentDirectory.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo 
{
[self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SavedImage.png"];
UIImage *image = imageView.image;
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
}
```

Now i have to include a 'Display' button on the first screen.
When tapped on the button, it will show a new view (modal view controller) and displays all the photos in thumbnails/tableview from the NSDocumentDirectory.

When a photo is selected, it will be deleted from the NSDocumentDirectory.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, while storing the image in Documents folder, try storing them with a naming convention like keep a counter variable and give your images names according to it. Some thing like this:

```
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", counter]];
```

Now, once you've all images stored in documents folder and wish to get all of them you can get them by writing this code:

```
 -(NSMutableArray *)GetImage:(NSMutableArray *)arrayImgNames
 {
      NSMutableArray *tempArray;
            for(int i=0;i<[arrayImgNames count]; i++)
     {
        NSArray *paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [arrayImgNames objectAtIndex:i]];
        [tempArray addObject:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];
        return tempArray;
     }
 }
```

Once you've got all images you can display them as thumbnails and then when you wish to delete an image use this method:

```
 -(int)removeImage:(NSString*)FileName1
 {
     NSFileManager *filemanager=[NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
     NSArray *path1=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);  
     NSString *documentdirectory = [path1 objectAtIndex:0]; 
     NSString *filepath=[documentdirectory  stringByAppendingPathComponent:FileName1];
     if([filemanager fileExistsAtPath:filepath]==TRUE)
     {
        [filemanager removeItemAtPath:filepath error:nil];
     }  
     return 0;
 }
```

I hope this helps you.

To Populate the table with image you'll need a custom cell. You can refer a tutorial by Apple called [AdvancedTableViewCells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedTableViewCells/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009111). It will show you how can you populate your table with images. They have a main thumbnail in every row. You have to customize it and make it 3 or 4 thumbnails as per your requirement. Other than that remove everything from that custom cell.

Comment: Thanks! But do you have any idea how to display the array of images into a new view with thumbnails?

Comment: Take a table. Makes its custom cell containing 3 of 4 images in one row whatever is convenient to you. Fill the images from the array of images which we have and you will have all images displayed. You'd also need a button for every image (a small cross on top right corner of every image) in the custom cell to delete the image.

Comment: Don't mind giving an example on how to populate the table with the array?

Comment: I edited my answer and have mentioned a tutorial which you can refer for populating your table using an array.

Comment: Thanks a lot, saviour. It would be a great help to me. But i have a question, is it possible to retrieve all the images if i don't save them with a counter as their naming convention?

Comment: Yes you can retrieve all images even without using a counter. But then you'd have to write that code inside GetImage: method explicitly for every image as you'd have to name every image separately and you cannot use a loop for that. Using a counter makes it easy to retrieve.

Comment: Also with the code you wrote, it will only save one image (the last selected) as you were naming all images saveimage.png so it will keep overwriting the old image. So while saving the image too you'd have to develop a mechanism so that you name every image separately. So to solve all this problems in one shot, use a counter. If you've any better technique you can use that as well.